# Get dictionary of label/phrase connections from classifier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nlp

I'm using `natural` for node:

```
const natural = require('natural');

const classifier = new natural.LogisticRegressionClassifier();

classifier.addDocument('label1', 'phrase1');
classifier.addDocument('label1', 'phrase2');
classifier.addDocument('label2', 'phrase3');
classifier.addDocument('label3', 'phrase4');

classifier.train();
```

How can I now get an object like

```
{
  "label1": "phrase1",
  "label1": "phrase2",
  "label2": "phrase3",
  "label3": "phrase4",
}
```

from `classifier`?

---

### My question

Given an instance of `natural.LogisticRegressionClassifier` how do I see what inputs labels and phrases were added as documents to create it?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `classifier.docs` gives you:

```
[
  { label: 'phrase1', text: [ 'label1' ] },
  { label: 'phrase2', text: [ 'label1' ] },
  { label: 'phrase3', text: [ 'label2' ] },
  { label: 'phrase4', text: [ 'label3' ] } 
]
```

so then you can `Array.prototype.reduce()` it:

```
'use strict';

const natural    = require('natural');
const classifier = new natural.LogisticRegressionClassifier();

classifier.addDocument('label1', 'phrase1');
classifier.addDocument('label1', 'phrase2');
classifier.addDocument('label2', 'phrase3');
classifier.addDocument('label3', 'phrase4');

const input = classifier.docs.reduce((prev, current) => {
    prev[current.text[0]] = current.label;
    return prev;
}, {});

console.log(input);
```

Comment: This doesn't output the list documents that I input

Comment: e.g. training with `create party:create party,join aaa:join party, etc.` produces `{"parti":"create party","invit":"invite party members","join":"join party"}`

Comment: I've added to the question

Comment: Your answer doesn't give the "input labels and phrases were added as documents to create" the classifier, e.g. try with more complex inputs rather than `label1` etc